# Creating Docker network with REST API using Python Django

Tags: python, django

This solution is to create a docker network using Docker supported APIs. For achieving this, I am using Python and Django framework for providing RESTful APIs.

```
cat network.py
from django.http import JsonResponse
import requests
import json

HEADERS = {"Content-Type" : "application/json", "Accept" : "application/json"}

def network_details():
    response = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:6000/networks")
    #table = [[Name, Id, Driver, Subnet, Gateway]]
    table = []
    details = {}
    for network in response.json():
        details["Name"] = network["Name"].encode("utf-8")
        details["Id"] = network["Id"].encode("utf-8")[:12]
        details["Driver"] = network["Driver"].encode("utf-8")

        #to check if dict is Null
        if network["IPAM"]["Config"].__len__() == 0:
            details["Subnet"] = "none" 
            details["Gateway"] = "none"
        else:
            ip_config = network["IPAM"]["Config"][0]

            details["Subnet"] = ip_config["Subnet"]
            details["Gateway"] = ip_config["Gateway"]

        table.append(details)
        #intializing to dict to None as scope is outside the for loop as well
        details = {}
    return table 

def network_info(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return JsonResponse(network_details(), safe=False)

def create_nw(content):
    response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:6000/networks/create", 
                            content, headers = HEADERS )   
    return response.json()

def create_network(request):   
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            response = create_nw(request.body)
            #explicitly looking for Warning or message to know the status
            if "Warning" in response:
                return JsonResponse("Success, Network created with ID: {}".
                                   format(response['Id'].encode('utf-8')[:12]),safe=False)
         elif "message" in response:
                return JsonResponse("Error : {}".
                                   format(response.values()[0]),safe=False)
        except ValueError:
        return JsonResponse("Error : Improper JSON format provided", safe=False)
```

URLs information:

```
cat urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views, images, containers, network

urlpatterns = [
              url(r'images', images.images_info),
              url(r'containers', containers.active_containers),
              url(r'network/create', network.create_network), 
              url(r'network', network.network_info), 
              url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
              ]
```

RESTful API to the solution:

```
curl -X POST <****>/network/create -d @create_network.json --header "Content-Type: application/json" | jq
```

Can someone suggest if this the right way to build an application using Django framework?

I am not looking for the appropriate/optimized solution for the idea I want to work on. I am looking for your suggestions how can I improve in my coding skills. The reason for selecting Django is to get hands on the framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for this .. is this all necessary? You could use the flask application , or mapping the each route to a script..

**Short answer** : No , there are others ways to build what you want that django is not more appropriate.

**Long answer**

### First point

In your methods you are handling the permited methods at hand , the django have the decorators that handle this:

**Allowed http methods**
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/decorators/#allowed-http-methods

Some methods would:

```
@require_http_methods(["GET"])
def list_containers(request):
    pass

@require_http_methods(["GET"])    
def list_images(request):
    pass

@require_http_methods(["GET","POST"])
def networks(request):

    if request.method == "GET":
        # retrieve networks and return them

    if method.method == "POST":
        # create network
```

urls.py

```
url(r'container/s', network.list_containers),
url(r'images/', network.list_images),
url(r'networks/', network.networks)
```

**P.s** : The views isn't following your structure , but is easily changed.

### Second point

The mainly problem with your code is the routes: **network/** and **network/create** to REST definition , the correct would be the route **/networks** receive the GET and POST and perform different actions ( retrieve and create respectively )

You could use the Django Rest Framework[1] ( the main framework to build restful application in django )

The DRF handle all these: method , routes , views ( viewsets ).

But if django is the bigger to this , you could use the flask framework and use the your routes and the restful frameworks that solves your problem too.

[1] http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

[2] http://flask.pocoo.org/ ( Framework )

[3] https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/ ( FlaskRestful )